# how to change text of button in listview in react native?

Tags: listview, react-native, react-native-listview

I am trying to change text of button which is in listview quickly after click on it?

I am trying with following code to implement this but i cant do it i.e its not working. How can i do it? please help.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      button_text:"Connect",
    }
  }

  ConPressed() {
    this.setState({
      button_text: "Connected",
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.sa}
        renderRow={(rowData) => 

       <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.ConPressed()}>
          <Text>{this.state.button_text}</Text>
       </TouchableHighlight>

      />
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export default class ListItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      button_text: 'Connect',
    }
  }


  ConPressed = () => {
    this.setState({ button_text: 'Connected' });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.ConPressed}>
        <Text>{this.state.button_text}</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
```

So now you want to import your ListItem in your original file, and use that in your `renderRow`.

`renderRow={() => <ListItem />}`

Comment: @mayureshpatil No problem :)

Comment: @MattyK14 it s problem calling onPress method without press TouchableOpacity.

Comment: @MattyK14 it's called without press on Touchable opacity, it called on initialization of screen.

Comment: @Rushitrivedi do you have a fat arrow function: `= () =>` ? If not, did you `bind(this)`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code for the touchable you are passing a method execution and not a method reference.

```
<TouchableHighlight
onPress={() => this.ConPressed()}>
<Text>{this.state.button_text}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Which means conPressed will get executed as soon as the component gets mounted which is probably why you are getting the error. Try changing it to

```
<TouchableHighlight
onPress={() => this.ConPressed}>
<Text>{this.state.button_text}</Text>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

And also

```
this.ConPressed = this.ConPressed.bind(this)
```

In your constructor

Comment: Can you confirm that ConPressed is getting called on button press?

Comment: yes i used same as you given in answer, it is getting called on `TouchableHighlight` i.e on button pressed.

Answer (score -1):

Bind `ConPressed()` to scope.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        button_text:"Connect",
    }
    this.ConPressed = this.Conpressed.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but its not working it showing error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.Conpressed.bind')`

Comment: sorry i miss a character this.ConPressed = this.Con"P"ressed.bind(this); :)

Comment: yes i did it. but also its not working, after pressing it showing same text that is `connect`. where it goes wrong?

Comment: can you give online snack expo for this like this `https://snack.expo.io/SywBhpMgW` it will helps me alot...

Comment: I found the problem apparently when a row is already rendered you can't update the props of it, you need to create a new object

Comment: @mayureshpatil yes you should create a custom component for the List that holds the state variable. You should also use `FlatList` & not `ListView`

Comment: @MattyK14 hello Thanks for reply, sorry but i cant get the clear idea you suggested can you please give some hint through code.