# How to change view for individual listview in react native?

Tags: listview, react-native, conditional-statements, states, onpress

I want to change the view of Follow button to unfollow on tap of particular listview button. Currently when I press on any follow button every follow button in listview changes to unfollow. i just want to change for particular follow button in listview?

[image: Iamge of follow button]

/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{Platform,StyleSheet,Text,View,Image,ListView,TouchableOpacity,ImageBackground,TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { TabNavigator, StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Col, Row, Grid } from 'react-native-easy-grid';
import { Container, Header, Content, Card, CardItem, Thumbnail, Button, Left, Body, Right } from 'native-base';
const instructions = Platform.select({
  ios: 'Press Cmd+R to reload,\n' +
    'Cmd+D or shake for dev menu',
  android: 'Double tap R on your keyboard to reload,\n' +
    'Shake or press menu button for dev menu',
});

export default class Followers extends Component{
  static navigationOptions = { 
      headerTitle: 'Followers',      
      headerTitleStyle: {
          color: '#36292a',
          fontFamily: 'WorkSans-Regular',
          fontWeight: '300',
          marginLeft: 0
          },
        };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      follow: true,
    };
  }

  updateSearchStatus = () => 
    this.setState({ 
      follow : this.state.follow,
  });

    updateTitleStatus = () =>
    this.setState({
    } , () => {
      //this.ButtonState();
      if(this.state.follow == true){
        this.setState({
          follow : false
        });
      }else{
        this.setState({
          follow : true
        });
      }      
  });



displayImages(users){
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return(  
    <View style={styles.container}>       
            <CardItem style={{height: 78,borderBottomWidth:1,borderColor: '#dadddf'}}>
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail source={{uri: users.avatar_url}} style={{height: 40, width: 40}} />
                <Body>
                  <Text style={styles.uploaderName}>{users.name}</Text>
                </Body>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <TouchableHighlight underlayColor = '#DFE1E3' onPress={this.updateTitleStatus} >
                  { this.state.follow ? <View style={styles.followouter}><Text style={{color:'#fefefe',fontSize: 12}}>Follow</Text></View> 

                       : <View style={styles.unfollowouter}><Text style={{color:'#36292a',fontSize: 12}}>Unfollow</Text></View> 

                    }
                </TouchableHighlight>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
       </View>      
    );
  }

  render() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    var users = [
      {
        name: 'Amy Farha',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/1c/f3/05/1cf305362aed02ad559f989687b1460e.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Chris Jackson',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a8/37/8e/a8378eeb01ec788a0068ea6b1b759091.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Amanda Martin',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8a/db/a7/8adba7207bdc82668bf06acc2734537e.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Amy Farha',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8a/db/a7/8adba7207bdc82668bf06acc2734537e.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Chris Jackson',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/66/f0/2f/66f02f37eb54ff7f79f4c831212b231f.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Amanda Martin',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/58/0c/78/580c789ded6ceeafdf71b792b0d57ac6.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Amy Farha',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a5/4d/4d/a54d4d37522a76a67002fa25b8e51515.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Chris Jackson',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/adhamdannaway/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/47/6b/5c/476b5c4c9725ff3cd4bb3e5f61e4d6c3.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Amanda Martin',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ad/4b/06/ad4b06523eefacc30d09d41a9992029f.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Christy Thomas',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kfriedson/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a5/4d/4d/a54d4d37522a76a67002fa25b8e51515.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Melissa Jones',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/nuraika/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/82/ac/2e/82ac2e1c86692090173666496b9ce1cf.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Amanda Martin',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/brynn/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/8a/db/a7/8adba7207bdc82668bf06acc2734537e.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Christy Thomas',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kfriedson/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/a5/4d/4d/a54d4d37522a76a67002fa25b8e51515.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Melissa Jones',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/nuraika/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/ae/b6/ac/aeb6ac2f05644f1464c298bf979630e9.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Christy Thomas',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/kfriedson/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/57/ac/3e/57ac3e724c61f9b9803d520574e42a1e.jpg',
      },
      {
        name: 'Melissa Jones',
        avatar_url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/nuraika/128.jpg',
        image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/564x/66/f0/2f/66f02f37eb54ff7f79f4c831212b231f.jpg',
      },
    ];

    var cloneUsers = ds.cloneWithRows(users);

    return (  
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>    
        <ListView
          style={styles.listView}
          dataSource={cloneUsers}
          renderRow={this.displayImages.bind(this)}
          renderSeparator={(sectionId, rowId) => <View key={rowId} style={styles.separator} />}
        />     
        </View>

    );  
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  icon: {
    width: 26,
    height: 26,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fefefe'
  },
  uploaderName:{
    fontSize: 16,
    color: '#36292a'
  },
  actionButtonIcon: {
    color: '#fefefe',  
  },
  followouter: {
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: 90, 
      height: 25, 
      borderRadius: 4,  
      backgroundColor: '#f00039'
    },
  unfollowouter: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
      width: 90, 
      height: 25, 
      borderRadius: 4, 
      borderWidth:1, 
      borderColor: '#999296',
  }

});
```

Comment: have you tried using switchable binding?

Comment: This should point you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326655/how-to-change-text-of-button-in-listview-in-react-native/48343063#48343063

Answer (score 0):

All button switch to unfollow because you are using the same state `this.state.follow` for all the button. So when it turns to false, all the buttons will display unfollow.

What you could do is to add an attribute `follow` in your user object and instead of testing `this.state.follow ?...` you can do `user.follow ?...`.

And in your `updateSearchStatus()` function, you could pass the user to be able to find it and to change his `follow`status.

Comment: I didn't get you answer. I am new to this. Can you help me with this in brief? TIA

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example for you:

> Create state for store which one is Clicked/Selected

```
this.state = { selected: null };
```

> Pass the item index which one is Clicked/Selected

```
updateSearchStatus = (index) => this.setState({ selected : index });
```

> Your **renderItem** should be make some condition on **Item Button**

```
<View style={ this.state.selected == item.index ? styles.followouter : styles.unfollowouter}>
    <Text style={{color:'#fefefe',fontSize: 12}}>
        {this.state.selected == item.index ? 'Follow' : 'Unfollow'}
    </Text>
</View>
```

> Hope it will help you for an idea

Comment: Hi @KamleshTilwani
the **item** is refer to **User** or each row or **user.id or user.index**

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this problem but my suggestion is this. 
In your project folder create a folder called **components** inside that folder create a file named **Toggle.js**. Inside that file use this code.

```
    export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isSelected: false,
      follow: true,
    }
  }
  updateTitleStatus = () =>
    this.setState({}, () => {
      if (this.state.follow == true) {
        this.setState({
          follow: false
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          follow: true
        });
      }
    });
  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='#DFE1E3' onPress={this.updateTitleStatus} >
        {this.state.follow ? <View style={styles.followouter}><Text style={{ color: '#fefefe', fontSize: 12 }}>Follow</Text></View>
          : <View style={styles.unfollowouter}><Text style={{ color: '#36292a', fontSize: 12 }}>Unfollow</Text></View>}
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  followouter: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 90,
    height: 25,
    borderRadius: 4,
    backgroundColor: 'dodgerblue'
  },
  unfollowouter: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: 90,
    height: 25,
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#999296',
  }
});
```

And then do this change in your current file.

```
    //.....
import Toogle from '../components/Toogle';
''''''
...
displayImages(users){
    var {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return(  
    <View style={styles.container}>       
            <CardItem style={{height: 78,borderBottomWidth:1,borderColor: '#dadddf'}}>
              <Left>
                <Thumbnail source={{uri: users.avatar_url}} style={{height: 40, width: 40}} />
                <Body>
                  <Text style={styles.uploaderName}>{users.name}</Text>
                </Body>
              </Left>
              <Right>
                <Toogle/>
              </Right>
            </CardItem>
       </View>      
    );
  }
......
....//
```

Hope this will help.